# Rendering Error with Devise and Mobylette

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, devise, config, renderer

I am using Mobylette with Devise on my Rails 4 app.

When I try to sign up, sign in, or reset my password on my mobile device I get this error:

> ActionController::MissingRenderer (No renderer defined for format:
>   mobile)

Has anyone else had this issue?

I've tried setting up a fallback chain

```
mobylette_config do |config|
  config[:fallback_chains] = {
    mobile: [:mobile, :html]
  }
end
```

and adding this to the devise initializer

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :mobile]
```

But continue to get the renderer error.

Any recommendations would be awesome, still new to mobile formatting.

Comment: Please add `include Mobylette::RespondToMobileRequests` in controller

Comment: I have that in my application_controller.rb - thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue with the following..

created an initializer and added this:

```
ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end
```

along with Preshant4020's suggestion

```
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]
```

in the devise initialize and got it to work with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]
```

Comment: thank you. Added this and also created an initializer with `ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end` and it worked